Lebesgue integral as the completion of the Riemann Integral
I’ve been skimming through my advanced calculus textbook and stumbled upon an interesting statement, that the space $\mathcal{L}[a, b]$ can be achieved as the completion of $\tilde{\mathcal{R}}[a, b]$ (the space of equivalence classes of Riemann integrable functions, where the equivalence relation is being different on a set of Lebesgue measure zero) with respect to the integral metric.
I am wondering whether there is a text that develops Lebesgue integral entirely from this definition, i.e., MCT, Fatou’s Lemma, DCT? I think this would be very fun to read.

This approach is used in Analysis in Euclidean Space (see Section 7.2) by Kenneth Hoffman (the "Hoffman" of the well-known linear algebra text) -- 1975 Prentice-Hall edition and 2007 Dover edition.
